# C++ Multi index table - eos persistance API

Tags: c++, templates, boost-multi-index, eos

The code snippet for this question is from the Persistance API section of the WIKI documentation for EOS. The link to this page is here...

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/wiki/Persistence-API

In the following code snippet, it looks like the class template (or template class) is being typedef'd as service_table_type. Then a whole bunch of custom types are passed within the angle brackets of the class template and there seems to be nothing new there apart from the complexity (if i understood it correctly).

```
using service_table_type = multi_index<service, service_rec,
indexed_by< N(bycustomer), const_mem_fun<service_rec, account_name, 
&service_rec::get_customer>>>;
```

My question is regarding the below line line of code that follows the above code snippet. what is going on here? it looks like a call to the function service_table() which returns a parameter of type service_table_type. From where did this function come from? If this function came from a library, how would it return the value of type service_table_type which we arbitrarily created?

```
service_table_type service_table( current_receiver(), mechanic );
```

could you provide me a stripped down generic code example of what's going on here?

Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling constructor of `multi_index` class. `service_table` is the variable name

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To test my understanding, I wrote a Test class which, to my understanding, mimics what's going on in the above code. My code works the way it is but when i include the lines commented out, it doesn't work. ( here i am assuming that the commented lines are analogous to: " using service_table_type = multi_index<service, service, .... and  " service_table_type service_table( current_receiver(), mechanic ); " respectively.

Comment: Sorry my edit timed out so I couldn't properly structure the above question. Here is the code that works as is. the commented out section doesn't work. what am i not doing that the example above is doing?        
    template<class T>
    class Test{
    private:
     T x;
                                 
    public:
        Test<T>(T templateVar){std::cout<<templateVar;}
        void setVar(T v) {x=v;}
        T getX() const {return x;}
    };
    int main()
   {
   // using xxx = Test<float>;
   //xxx obj(25.003); 
   Test<float> obj(25.003); 
    return 0; 
   }`

Comment: What you mean by "it doesn't work"? It doesn't compile? Check that you've enabled C++11. Alternatively you may change `using xxx = Test<float>` to `typedef Test<float> xxx;`